# Show that every closed and bounded set in $\Bbb R$ is compact. Does the same hold in $\Bbb Q$? If not, then give an example.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that every closed and bounded set in $\Bbb R$ is compact. Does the same hold in $\Bbb Q$? If not, then give an example.

This was a strange question, I encountered. I have no problem with the statement that "every closed and bounded set in $\Bbb R$ is compact." This is because, it's immediate from the Heine-Borel Theorem. But the problem is with this question, i.e

> Does the same hold in $\Bbb Q$? If not, then give an example.

By the phrase, "*does the same*", I feel the thing meant is,

> If a set is bounded and closed in $\Bbb Q$, then is it necessary, that the set is compact in $\Bbb Q$ ? If not, then give an example.

This is what I inferred the question to be. My version of Heine-Borel Theorem is:

"A set $K\subset \Bbb R$ is compact if and only if, $K$ is closed and bounded."

From the theorem, I can assert that any set (which is a subset of $\Bbb R$,) that is closed and bounded is a compact set. Now, "a set in $\Bbb Q$ " probably means that all the elements of the set are in $\Bbb Q.$

Now, we come back to our question. It conatins a phrase "If a set is bounded and closed in $\Bbb Q$". I infer that this means that if the set is $A$ which is closed and bounded in $\Bbb Q$ then, it means that all the limit points of the set $A$ are in $\Bbb Q$ and the limit points, in addition belongs to $A$ as well and $\exists M\in \Bbb Q$ such that $|a|\leq M,\forall a\in A.$ Now, as $A\subset \Bbb Q\subset\Bbb R,$ so from Heine-Borel Theorem, we can conclude that $A$ is essentially compact.

Hence, we can say, "Yes, *the same thing*  holds in $\Bbb Q.$"

Am I correct in my reasoning(s) ? I am overwhelmed slightly by the strangeness of this question.

*I want to add that I have no idea, about what a topologic /metric /euclidean space is. This was a question proposed in the topic called ," Basic Topology of $\Bbb R$" in a real analysis course. The book that was recommended for studing this topic called "Basic Topology in $\Bbb R$" is the book, "Understanding Analysis" by Stephen Abbott.*

Comment: Did you learn about subspace topology, or topology given to subset of R?

Comment: @Abastro Unfortunately, no. I studied this topic "Basic Topology in $\Bbb R$" from the book, Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott.

Comment: Hmm, never faced that material. You would need a way to identify which set is an open set in Q - can you?

Comment: @Abastro I only learned the definition of an open set/closed set/limit points/derived set/compact set in $\Bbb R.$ I think that's why the name of the course was, "Basic Topology in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I dont know, what a metric space is? So, no that is not answering my question. As, I said/mentioned in OP at the bottom part marked with italics, you might get an idea about my situation. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the word "metric" space here. It is just the usual Euclidean distance. And it does answer your question in the negative. There you have your counterexample. Take all rational numbers in $(-\pi,\pi)$ for example.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But what's wrong with my reasoning here ? The question, if I am inferring correctly asserts that, all the limit points of the subset of rational numbers are rational as well and belongs to the subset.

Comment: See Diego's answer in the duplicate, why your reasoning is not correct. This set is not compact relatively to $\Bbb R$. If you know what "complete"means, then this is another idea.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Now, that you mentioned, I took a look at Diego's answer. I think the crisp of my concern is hidden in the line, "Clearly $S$ is not compact in $\mathbb R$, then $S$ is not compact in $\mathbb Q$," in his answer. But the point is: The reasoning given by him is, "$S$ is compact relatively to $\mathbb Q$ if and only if $S$ is compact relatively to $\mathbb R$." Is this statement somekind of a theorem ? But then again, a set compact in $\Bbb R$ might not be compact in $\Bbb Q.$ Am I missing something?

Comment: No, it is just the definition of compactness using coverings. How did your lecture define a compact set?

Comment: @DietrichBurde The definition of compact sets, we were introduced to was :"A set $K\subset \Bbb R$ is compact if every sequence in $\Bbb R$ has a convergent subsequence that converges to a point in $K.$" An alternative definition was suggested that, "A set $K\subset \Bbb R$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded." Finally, they said, that these two definitions of compactness are equivalent to this third (alternative) definition as well, which says, "A set $K\subset \Bbb R$ is compact iff for every  open cover of the set, there exists a finite subcover."

Comment: I mean the last definition.

Comment: @DietrichBurde so, that means if I understand the situation correctly, it just boils down to this that: "A set $K\subset \Bbb R$ is compact iff for every  open cover of the set, there exists a finite subcover" *and* "$S$ is compact relatively to $\mathbb Q$ if and only if $S$ is compact relatively to $\mathbb R$,"  are equivalent statements ? But then I ask how? As this don't seem apparent to me at all.

Comment: From what I see in your reasoning, the issue lies in the fact that you're thinking of compactness as an absolute property of some set, which it is not. Compactness of a set $X$ is a property relative to the "bigger" set it lives in. A set $X\subset\Bbb R$ is compact (in $\Bbb R$) if any open cover of $X$ by sets (of $\Bbb R$) has a finite subcover. When you talk about compactness of $X$ relative to $\Bbb Q$, the definition of compactness will be talking about coverings with sets from $\Bbb Q$ having finite subcover, which may or may not hold even when it is compact relative to $\Bbb R$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Is there a definition for compactness for sets in Q? This is because, all I know is the definitions of compactness in R. I showed that all rational limit points are in A, so A is definitely closed in Q. Also, A is bounded by a rational. So, can't ws say, that A is compact in Q ?

Comment: @ThomasFinley you may inspect if all sequence has a convergent subsequence (it does not). Still do not know why closedness of subset is not yet introduced.

Comment: @Abastro Is this the rule/law/definition that: "A set $A,$ is compact in $\Bbb Q$ iff the set is compact in $\Bbb R$".

Comment: Is this from the first edition of Understanding Analysis? I cannot find it in my copy of the second edition.

Comment: @ZoeHillcrest No, the problem is not from the book, "Understanding Analysis" by Stephen Abbott. I was just trying to say, that the book was being followed in my course. So, my knowledge about topology in $\Bbb R$ is what is given in the book, in Ch-3  which goes by the name, "Basic Topology in $\Bbb R$".

Comment: @ThomasFinley as I mentioned earlier, you can take “every sequence has a converging subsequence” as a definition. Think by yourself that if compactness in Q is the same as compactness in R, it should be quite straightforward.

Comment: I see. To me, the question seems a little unfair then... Chapter 3 only gives a definition for $K \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ to be compact in $\mathbf{R}$ and nothing else.

Comment: @ZoeHillcrest I agree with you completely.

Comment: I just added a [more detailed explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719339/386889) in the "duplicate" which did not answer your question (why "$S$ is compact relatively to $\mathbb Q$ if and only if $S$ is compact relatively to $\mathbb R$"?).

Comment: Beware that 1) the general definition of compactness (with open covers) is equivalent to [sequential compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space) in any [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) like $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Q,$ but not in general topological spaces; 2) the criterion "compact iff closed and bounded" holds in $\Bbb R^n$ but not in infinite dimensional normed vector spaces.

Comment: Note that @PrasunBiswas's comment above was wrong. Compactness *is* an absolute notion, as also detailed in the previously mentionned ["more detailed explanation"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719339/386889).